# Is it possible to add or edit rows in a protected excel worksheet?

Tags: .net, excel, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, closedxml

We are generating an excel with more than 25 columns using `ClosedXML` in `.Net Core MVC` application. Here, we want to protect certain columns and restrict the user from editing those. To achieve this, we have successfully implemented the `Protect Worksheet` feature. But, now there is an additional requirement came saying that the user need an option to 'add or delete' rows from this sheet. Since, the protection is already done for the worksheet, we are not able to implement this add/delete rows.

Is there any way to implement this feature ?

Comment: Unprotect the sheet, add the rows, re-protect the worksheet, unless you mean the users are doing this manually?

Comment: No. Once the file is downloaded, they may need to add or delete certain rows, but they are not allowed to modify certain existing data in columns.

Answer (score 3):

> But, now there is an additional requirement came saying that the user need an option to 'add or delete' rows from this sheet.

Yes there is. When you protect the worksheet, set `AllowInsertingRows` and `AllowDeletingRows` as `True`

```
ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

Check out the syntax of [Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)

Comment: We have tried this approach, but it didn't worked.

Comment: It works. Please share the code that you tried.